# css empty pseudo class not working with dynamic update in Safari

Tags: css, safari

Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/aGv2j/)

```
table:empty {
    display: none;
}

<table style="border: 5px solid green;"></table>
<button></button>

<script>
$("button").click(function () {
    $("table").html("<tbody></tbody>");
});
</script>
```

When dynamic updating content with :empty pseudo class Safari not working.

Works in Chrome, but not in Safari.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use jQuery to hide empty table. It supports all the browsers. The issue is still genuine because Safari supports `:empty`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar problem here.
I managed to make it work just by "resetting" styles:
try adding  `.css({display: 'initial'}).css({display: ''})`

```
<script>
$("button").click(function () {
    $("table").html("<tbody></tbody>").css({display:'initial'}).css({display: ''});
});
</script>
```

Hope it works for You